# How I can do custom css for bootstrap table class 'table table-bordered '? It is not working for me

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web design. Please help.

I am using bootstrap 3.0. I have one table with below data....

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 1</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="found">
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="found">
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="found">
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="found">
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="found">
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="found">
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to use custom site.css file with below custom class..

I want to use class selector for "table" and " table-bordered".
So I code like below.. class name is dash.

```
   table.table-bordered.dash {
    width:100%
    }
```

so first line of code will be like this...

```
<table class="dash">
```

instead of writing

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
```

I want to write something like below

```
<table class="dash">
```

but it is not working.. please help.

Comment: Question is not clear. Actually what is your need specify it clearly and you are inherited style like `table.table-bordered.dash` so you must add  `<table class="table table-bordered dash">` to ur html

Comment: I want to add custom class like above mention for class dash...

Comment: @Vivek is right.. you need to use table table-bordered to inherit the styles.. http://www.bootply.com/xBlz0WDFlI

Comment: is it possible to add custom single class for both 'table' and 'table-bordered' or these inherited styles in single custom class? is any other way? By adding custom class it will be easy for entire class..

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for 100% width

```
<table class=" col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 table table-bordered">
...
</table>
```